# How can I get request links from one original link? (Get the requests links you see in developer console)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

[image: Here is what I mean]

I have no idea how to get those links.  Does someone know how I would get the other links by requesting the original link that is in the address bar?

By the way those API links are JSON data.

Comment: first check what you have in HTML which you get from original link - maybe these links are somewhere in HTML. And then you use `requests` to get HTML and `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` to search data in HTML.

Comment: if there is no links in HTML then usually there are values which you can use to generate these links - For example I see in HTML `6277` and `LIRIK` which are in these links and probably other pages use similar links but they change only `6277` and `LIRIK` into different values - so you can manually copy these links and reuse them for other pages with different values from other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply click on it you would open the headers tab and then copy link. See the picture below.

[image: blabla]

I have created a python code for you.Simply paste the copied link in the URL variable
and get the json format.

```
import requests

url = "https://sullygnome.com/api/charts/linecharts/getconfig/ChannelFollowers/7/0/62277/LIRIK/%20/%20/0/0/%20/"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
  'Referer': 'https://sullygnome.com/channel/lirik',
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
}


response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```